# Собирательные числительные с сущ. женского рода

Tags: морфология, числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание, собирательные-числительные

В моей книге написано:

> Собирательные числительные
> употребляются: 1) с существительными
> мужского и общего рода, называющими
> лиц мужского пола: *двое учеников*,
> *трое сирот*.

Значит ли это, что собирательные числительные нельзя употреблять с существительными женского рода? К примеру: *двое женщин*, *трое табуреток*, *четверо скотин*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы правильно поняли. С существительными женского рода употребляются количественные числительные: две женщины, три табуретки...